# Installing Azure CLI 2.0 offline

Tags: command-line, azure

Is there a way to install Azure CLI 2.0 just by using an .exe file or something similar? I am asking because I want to install it on a Windows Server with no internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can download Azure CLI 2.0 MSI from this [link](https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCliWindows). In this way, we can install Azure CLI 2.0 offline.

Here is the link address:

https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCliWindows

Comment: there is a problem with the link, it never starts the downloading process. Could you please update with a new link?

Comment: Do you mean you can't open it? It works fine for me, just click it, IE or other browser will download it.